# userscript did run on greasemonkey addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts

I could install the userscript[1] successfully;Both greasemonkey and the userscript are definitively enabled ; checking the Errors console see nothing unusual. But the script below did not running as expected (no alert after a page is ready). Any idea will be appreciated.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          clicksave
// @namespace     http://userscripts.org/users/pierr
// @description   click the words and it will be saved
// @copyright     pierr chen
// @contributor   pierr chen
// @include       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js
// @license       GPL version 3 or any later version; http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
// @license       Creative Commons; http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/
// @version       0.0.1
// ==/UserScript==

function getSelText()
{
    var txt = '';
     if (window.getSelection)
    {
        txt = window.getSelection();
             }
    else if (document.getSelection)
    {
        txt = document.getSelection();
            }
    else if (document.selection)
    {
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
            }
    else return;

    return txt
}

function saveSelText()
{
    var selText = getSelText()
    if (selText != "")
    {
        var url = "http://localhost:3000/auto_create?content="+getSelText();
        $.get(url,{},false);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        alert('Handler for .mouseup called.');  //even this alert will not jump out
        saveSelText()
    })

})
```

[1]http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/96771

Comment: I guess, jquery | $ function not load yet when you called $(document); try adding `alert($);` before that line.

Comment: Alert is not a debugger. Use console.log() for that - if you have FireBug installed. ;)

Comment: @Mark. Adding that did not produce any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out should use
`// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js`

> Some versions of jQuery will not run inside the Greasemonkey sandbox. As of this writing, 1.3.2 does work, but 1.4.1 does not. It is possible to patch 1.4 versions of jQuery to work, see jQuery Forum: Importing jQuery 1.4.1 into greasemonkey scripts generates an error